# Update a MySQL table that has only one row with no id column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table called settings. It has multiple columns, where every column is an item with a single value. So it has only one row and no id column. The design is final (I don't plan to add more columns).

How can I update the value in a single column (change one setting's value)?

Comment: Every table should have some kind of ID field which acts as primary key. Using the primary key, you can update a single row.

Comment: @Nero you don't ever know, what the requirement would be..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the problem with using this --> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html
?

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = value
```

In case you have more than one row, you can add:

```
WHERE table1.column = matching_value;
```

making sure the match criteria is only the row you need.

Answer (score 0):

to update a value of certain item column you must specify the row contains the value to be updated, since you don't have a primary key, you can depend on the nature of item values to act as row identifier and i don't recommend that.. the best way is to update your design and add column for the primary key